# Possible Wordpress exploitation

Tags: wordpress, security, phishing

Does anybody know of a security vulnerability in Wordpress whereby fraudsters are sending out banking phishing emails (purporting to be banks) with a login link pointing to a valid domain but with extended path that may be unknown to the legitimate owner of the domain?

For Example:

```
href = [HOST]=http://www.ponnuki.net
   [EXTENSION] = /wordpress/MOBILE-DO/absa-mobiledo/absaBanking/index.php
```

Judging from the number of these I have been receiving recently, it appears that the hosts are not geo-specific, so the obvious conclusion is that they are seeking out vulnerable hosts to piggy-back on.

Can someone recommend who would be the best to report this to?

Comment: This may be a better fit for wordpress.stackexchange.com. Is your Wordpress installation up to date? The answer below is also good.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe you have found a security issue with Wordpress, see below.

> For actual security issues with the self-hosted version of WordPress,
>   then you should send an email with the details to security [at]
>   wordpress.org. Include as much detail as you can.

Taken from the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Security_FAQ).

Comment: Thank Sarah. I will send them what I have.